# Python lxml XPath with deep nesting with specific search

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

The xpath for text I wish to extract is reliably located deep in the tree at

```
...table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]
```

Specifically, td[2] is structured like so

```
<td class="val">xyz</td>
```

I am trying to extract the text "xyz", but a broad search returns multiple results. For example the following path returns 10 elements.

```
xpath('//td[@class="val"]')
```

... while a specific search doesn't return any elements. **I am unsure why the following returns nothing.**

```
xpath('//tbody/tr/td[@class="val"]')
```

One solution involves..

```
table = root.xpath('//table[@class="123"]')

#going down the tree
xyz = table[0][3][1]
print vol.text
```

**However, I am pretty sure this extremely brittle. I would appreciate it if someone could tell me how to construct an xpath search that would be both un-brittle and relatively cheap on resources**

Comment: can you just paste some valid xml, to test with, instead of giving `...table/tbody/...'

Comment: Please provide an example XML document. If it's longer than, say, 10 lines, you can upload it at [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com) or [gist](https://gist.github.com/)

Comment: or you can trim the xml document, use it in python code and paste the sample python code showing the problem, I would like to copy paste and run your code and see problem e.g. something similar to my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't mentioned it explicitly, but if your target `table` and `td` tag classes are reliable then you could do something like:

```
//table[@class="123"]/descendant::td[@class="val"]
```

And you half dodge the issue of `tbody` being there or not.

However, there's no substitute for actually seeing the material you are trying to parse for recommending XPATH queries...

Answer (score 2):

```
...table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]
```

I guess you found this XPath via a tool like Firebug. One thing to note about tools like Firebug (or other inspect tools within browsers) is that they use the DOM tree generated by the browser itself and most (if not all) HTML parsers in browsers would try hard to make the passed HTML valid. This often requires adding various tags the standard dictates.

`<tbody>` is one of these tags. [`<tr>` tags are only allowed as a child of `<thead>`, `<tbody>` or `<tfoot>` tags.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.3) Unfortunately, in my experience, you will rarely see one of these tags inside a `<table>` in the actual source, but a browser would add these necessary tags while parsing to make HTML valid since [standard requires to do so](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/NOTE-xhtml-media-types-20090116/#C_19).

**To cut this story short, there is probably no `<tbody>` tag in your actual source. That is why your XPath returns nothing.**

As for generating XPath queries, this highly depends on the particular page/xml. In general, positional queries such as `td[4]` should be the last resort since they tend to break easily when something is added before them. You should inspect the markup carefully and try to come up queries that use attributes like `id` or `class` since they add specificity more reliably than the positional ones. But in the end, it all boils down to the specifics of the page in question.

Comment: You could add a little emphasis on your point: *there is no `tbody` in the source*

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be working

```
from lxml import etree

doc = etree.HTML('<html><body><table><tbody><tr><td>bad</td><td class="val">xyz</td></tr></tbody></table></body></html>')
print doc.xpath('//tbody/tr/td[@class="val"]')[0].text
```

output:

```
xyz
```

So what is your problem?